# "onOnSomething" naming method convention

Tags: java, naming, conventions

i have the following classes in my project:

Archer(who inherits from Character), Character(who inherits from TargetableObject) and TargetableObject.

then, TargetableObject has a method called "die()" that calls an abstract method called onDie(implemented in Character).
then again, the implementaition of Character's onDie calls another abstract method to be implemented in Archer.

So, i don't know how to name that method, by now it's onOnDie, but there's probably something more apropriated, maybe even something conventioned like the "on" itself.

Sorry for my bad english, ty for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename your onDie() method as die() and then override the original die() in the classes that inherit from TargetableObject. Here's the documentation regarding overriding: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: You can then use super() to call the parts of the method from the previous die() method.

Comment: oh! its perfect, i didn't know about super() calls in methods, ty!